# Can't run react-native project in android studio on mac version found: N/A

Tags: react-native, macos

Trying to run a `react-native` project on android studio with mac os and android device.
When I run `react-native doctor`, I get this
Ignore the device adb error, the main problem is the version found: N/A error, I can't seem to fix it, I've tried reinstalling android studio, setting the Paths again of `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME`, still getting the same error. Help
This is the LOG

[image: Image for Log]

Comment: Hi @Shreedhar Patil. can you share a log from android studio?

Comment: Hi @SallyAzulay I've edited the post and added the log, wasn't able to paste an image in comments for some reason, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Can you share the entire android studio screenshot? 
Does you have the play sign open there or it's grayed out?